# Generate Kotlin class diagram

Tags: uml, kotlin

I'm looking for a tool, Intellij Idea plugin, or whatever that is able to generate UML class diagram from Kotlin source files.

Intellij Idea 15's "Show diagram..." tool only works for .java files.

Google doesn't help, but I still hope there is a chance to find a tool for this.

Comment: If what you need is not implemented as an IDEA plugin, then I doubt it is implemented in any other way. Kotlin is a young language, not even out of beta, and its syntax can still change a bit. In order to generate UML from source files, you'd need to parse the language syntax, so such a tool isn't likely to be developed until 1.0 release.

Comment: don't Java tools work? I believe that Java reflection should understand Kotlin's classes as usual.

Comment: Suseika: this is what I was afraid of.

Comment: Vodden: I don't know about any tool that generates UML from class files, but if you know one, let me know and I'll give it a try. I think that would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it works but with limitations: you can click only on a package in the project tree and click "Show Diagram...". Also it generates diagram from the Java point of view (shows Java's signatures and facade classes)

[image]

Comment: When do you plan to support this feature fully with Kotlin?

Comment: As far as I know there are no plans for now as everybody is focused on the release and the language finalization. So I wouldn't expect full support soon however I believe there will nothing bad to open related tickets in the tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT